# TypeScript: How to types destructured parameters using spread syntax?

Tags: typescript

There exists the exact same question, but it was about array parameters.

How do I type str in this case?

```
const func = ({str, ...rest})=>{//doStuff}
```

This did not work:

```
const func = ({str, ...rest}:{str:string})=>{//doStuff}
```

This neither:

```
const func = ({str, ...rest}:{str:string; ...rest:any[]})=>{//doStuff}
```

Comment: Please show how your function is supposed to look like and work in JS

Comment: @miensol Why?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

```
type Func = (arg: {str: string} & {[key: string]: any}) => any

const func: Func = ({str, ...rest})=>{/* doStuff */}
```